# What is the best way to iterate over Map<String, List<Class>>

Tags: android, kotlin

I have variable that contain data structure like this:

```
       {
 "john" = [
  Data(date=2020-1-22, age=23),
  Data(date=2020-1-24, age=24),
  Data(date=2020-1-25, age=25)
                ],

  "Bob" = [
  Data(date=2023-1-22, age=34),
  Data(date=2018-1-22, age=75),
  Data(date=2020-2-22, age=16)
                ]

}
```

What is the best way to iterate over this structure in order to display it nicely/sum specific data etc..

Comment: Its a `MAP` so just use a `iterator` ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use "mapOf" ( I'm using Kotlin ) to make this case.
This is an example code to help your case.

```
data class Data(val date: String, val age: Int)

fun main() {
    val arrayOne = ArrayList<Data>()
    arrayOne.add(Data("2020-1-22", 23))
    arrayOne.add(Data("2020-1-24", 24))

    val arrayTwo = ArrayList<Data>()
    arrayTwo.add(Data("2020-1-22", 34))
    arrayTwo.add(Data("2020-1-22", 72))

    val dataMaps = mapOf(
        "John" to arrayOne,
        "Bob" to arrayTwo
    )
    println("Key : $dataMaps")
}
```

Comment: OP wants to iterate over the collection not want to create the collection.